# In java, what is the difference between (int)(Math.random()) and Math.random()?

Tags: java

What **exactly** does the (int) before the (Math.random()) do to it? I know it has to do with getting an integer out of the Math.random() but I can't really understand how it does that. I can't understand how this (int) works. I mean, for example, how do I use it in other ways?

Comment: What do you know about casting?

Comment: Learn about it. That's where the answer is hidden.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The (int) casts the double result of Math.random() to an integer.
So **(int) Math.random() always is zero**, because random() returns a number greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1.0

```
int i = (int)Math.random();
double d =  Math.random();

System.out.println(i);
System.out.println(d);
```

If you need integer randoms, you need first to multyply the result of random

```
int factor = 100;
i = (int)(Math.random() * factor);
System.out.println(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

The signature of `Math.random()` is `public static double random()` meaning it returns a `double` value.

If for some reason you want an integer then you should cast this value to an `int`. 
To make it brief it cuts any digit after the point part in your double.

e.g. `1.2` would become `1` 
`2.45` would become `2` etc

P.S. you should really read about casting to get the general idea how and when to use it.

Edit:

like @FlorentBayle commented casting the number generated by `double()` will always return `0` since it's range is `[0,1)` `0` inclusive, `1` exclusive that is. So, you must multiply it with an `int` which is equal to the max number of your desired range:

e.g. to get `int` into range `[0,5)` you should use:

```
int i = (int) (Math.random()*5);
```

Comment: [`Math.random()` "returns a double value with a positive sign, greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1.0."](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random()), so, casting it to an `int` will always return `0`.

Answer (score 1):

This syntax is a *cast*. It's a way of directly converting between types; the most usual use case is to convert a value of a particular type to a specific subtype when you know that the particular instance is really that subtype, e.g.:

```
abstract class Parent {...}
class Child extends Parent {...}

Parent myObject = ... //we know it's *really* a Child
Child myObject2 = (Child) myObject;
```

Note that this is an *unsafe* operation: if `myObject` is actually a different subclass of `Parent`, it will fail at runtime (by throwing `ClassCastException`). For this reason casts should usually be avoided. While the compiler may refuse to compile some provably wrong casts, most of the time you can override the type system, casting anything to anything, and failures will only happen at runtime.

Casts between primitive types are special-cased, and safer (although I would still advise avoiding them where possible, since they *look* like unsafe code; `Double.valueOf(Math.random()).intValue()` obtains the same result in a visibly safe way, and the performance cost, though real, is irrelevant to most programs). See section 5.1.3 of the JLS.

Comment: A cast of a scalar value is entirely different from a cast of an object reference.  And both are perfectly "safe".

Answer (score 0):

Math.Random() is just a wrapper around java.util.Random();

So instead, make a

```
Random rnd = new java.util.Random(); //costly operation so use only once
rnd.nextInt();                       //keep using nextwhatever for further operations
```